# How to obtain information about the time format (12/24) from Angular Locale?

Tags: javascript, angular, internationalization

having a string representing the language (optionally with country info), how can I know if the time should be shown as 12H or 24H ?

for example

```
is12HFormat('en_EN') // returns true
is12HFormat('es_ES') // returns false
```

Note that I do not want to use a pipe to show a time in a specific format, just find out if one or the other should be used.

**EDIT**:

currently using:

```
 private guessIf12HTimeFormat(language: string): boolean {
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 12, 3, 0, 0));
    const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString(language);
    return (!!dateString.match(/am|pm/i) || !!date.toString().match(/am|pm/i));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

See
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Note the hour12 option.

hour12: Whether to use 12-hour time (as opposed to 24-hour time). Possible values are true and false; **the default is locale dependent**.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve I would also recommend checking out moment.js which has "robust support for internationalization".

Perhaps:

```
var format = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es-ES');
var usedOptions = format.resolvedOptions();
var use24 = !usedOptions.hour12;
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but I'm wondering if by **not** specifying the hour12 option it works out the format based on the locale.

Comment: so the solution would be to generate a dummy time, specifying a locale, but not the hour12 option and then parse it to guess which one has Date.prototype used? - sounds rather involved.. but I guess it would work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647918/detect-with-javascript-if-users-machine-is-using-12-hour-clock-am-pm-or-24-cl

Comment: I've started this test codepen but it's not returning the correct result yet: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YrOGYp

Comment: It looks like I did, can you reapply your change so I can see what you did?

Comment: private guessIf12HTimeFormat(language: string): boolean {
    const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 12, 3, 0, 0));
    const dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString(language);
    return (!!dateString.match(/am|pm/i) || !!date.toString().match(/am|pm/i));
  }

Comment: codepen with your latest code - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wrEgqG - seems to work, not sure if it's correct for all cultures, e.g. Arabic.

Comment: i think there must be some way to access the hour12 value for a locale but cant work it out.

Comment: according to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34950/which-large-countries-use-12-hour-time-format-am-pm, there should be true for "en" but also for "ar-sa" and "es-co". For the last two does not work, which makes me think that it ignores the country and returns the response based on language alone

Comment: alternatively you could try moment.js and check for HH:mm vs hh:mm for a locale. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/ ... probably not what you're after though....

Comment: ive been looking for a better solution but havent found anything. could you store your own list to lookup the value?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/43dwH.jpg could you create a list of the countries (or culture codes) where the 12 hr format applies? I might be wrong, but dont think theres a reliable way to do it cross browser

Comment: I would like to avoid creating a list that I need to update manually in the (unlikely) case that a new country decides to suddenly start using 24H. Since it is not a critical issue, the solution proposed in the question does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using vanila JavaScript. Here is the example.

`var date = new Date();`

Here setting hour12: true comes as 12 hour format

`date.toLocaleString('en-US', {hour12: true})`

[image]

Comment: your example works by comparing the countryInfo with some predefined hardcoded variable. What I would like is a function that receives the language and returns true if 12H is the expected format and false if 24H. 

Like I said, no interest in using it to format a time string.

Answer (score 0):

For folks stumbling on this, You can somewhat introspect the options a format uses by default via `DateTimeFormat.resolvedOptions`, but you need to ensure that you specify an `hour` as part of the format otherwise it's likely to be left out at least in some environments

```
const options = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', {
  hour: 'numeric',
}).resolvedOptions();

alert(options.hour12)
```

Use either the whatever the local you wish here.