# Determine locale meridiem in moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I would like to call moment to return a bool to determine if the users locale (browser environment?) is using 12 hour or 24 hour clock (So I can set a flag for clock picker).

something like:
`var IsTwelveHourClock = moment.something()`

I could not see anything obvious from the moment docs that could help with this so hoping for some suggestions! Thanks

Comment: this would require javascript in a web page to be able to access information in the host OS that it really has no need to access - in short, there's nothing available to see if the user prefers 12 or 24 hour format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the language of the browser with that:

```
let userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

It will output, in my case, `de-DE`. Moment.js just needs the `de` without the `-DE` as i know so you should split it.

```
let userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
let local = userLang.split("-")[0];
```

And now you can set the moment.js locale like this

```
moment.locale(local);
```

With this code you can check if the user is using military time or not:

```
  var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 12, 3, 0, 0));
  var dateString = date.toLocaleTimeString();

  //apparently toLocaleTimeString() has a bug in Chrome. toString() however 
  //returns 12/24 hour formats. If one of two contains AM/PM execute 12 hour 
  //coding.
  if (dateString.match(/am|pm/i) || date.toString().match(/am|pm/i) )
  {
    //12 hour clock
    console.log("12 hour");
  }
  else
  {
    //24 hour clock
    console.log("24 hour");
  }
```

Original Post: [Detect with javascript if user's machine is using 12 hour clock (am/pm) or 24 clock (military time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647918/detect-with-javascript-if-users-machine-is-using-12-hour-clock-am-pm-or-24-cl)

Comment: Thanks! so that is how I set the locale....but for using another library like clock picker it needs to know whether to show a 24 hour clock or a 12 hour clock. Could I derive this from the locale?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have found another way as well!

var isTwelveHourClock = moment('LT').length > 5;

In a twelve hour the value (from moment.js docs) is something like `08:30 PM` or `20:30` in other locales.

Comment: got too excited there haha should be moment.format('LT')

Comment: It's the only solution that looks working :)